# How can I remove the gap between two side by side asp.net label controls?

Tags: css, asp.net

I build a progress bar using two ASP.net label controls. The label on the left has a green background and the label on the right has a red. Their total length is 100px. So if your progress is 75% the green label will be 75px long and the red label will be 25px long.

But there is a visible gap between the two controls like this:

> GGGGGGG RRR

and I want it to look like this:

> GGGGGGGRRR

Pretend "G" = green and "R" = red.

I tried using css with this but it did not work:

```
.pbar {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you illustrate your issue withing a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have two labels:

```
<label class='green'>GGGGGGGGGG</label>
<label class='red'>RRRRRRRRRR</label>
```

the following css will have the effect you are looking for:

```
label {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.green{
  background-color:green;
}
.red{
  background-color:red;
}
```

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bz1znu4v/2/

Comment: I should have mentioned that they are asp.net label controls. It may not matter. I trying your examples now.

Comment: @Roto - view the source of the page after it has been rendered because an `asp:label` may be converted to a `span`.

Comment: I added the float: left to my css and it works perfectly, thanks so much.

Comment: @Roto - glad to have helped, please mark as answer by clicking on the check sign. thanks!

Comment: man, I never know about the check sign. I feel guilty for all the people who have helped me in the past. Thanks again

Comment: @Roto - that's OK. you can go back on your questions and mark the right answers at any time

Answer (score 0):

Just place the labels of the two items in the same line, remove space between them. look for the example:

```css
.pbar {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="pbar">label 1</label><label class="pbar">label 2</label>
<hr>
<div>
  <label class="pbar">label 3</label>
  <label class="pbar">label 4</label>
</div>
```

Comment: 1st. the question is about labels, not spans. 2nd. if there's a css class like the following, your "solution" will not work: `span { margin:5px; }`

Comment: Correct for the 1st point, but my answer works anyway if you use span or labels. I've mistaken doing the first example with span, but I'll correct it. But I don't understan your point 2, why to put a margin if he is trying to avoid spaces?

Comment: I should have mentioned that they are asp.net label controls. It may not matter. I trying your examples now.

Comment: @JordiFlores - "he" may not have written any css but each browser (or library) have their own default css. so you should not assume that placing labels or spans on the same line will remove any margin or padding